# How to find corresponding name/value from cell on one sheet and substract it's number from corresponding cell on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, find, match

I need to find corresponding name of part and substract it's number on another sheet, but only if there is a number to substract (number greater than 0)
I need to spread this for every sum of parts (currently in row 61, but i will change this later if needed)
This needs to be on click of a button (i know how to assign VBA under button).

- if there is C30>0
- find text from sheet PortBoardVariations cell C60 matching text from sheet PartsWarehouse from cells in range A:A
- substract value PortBoardVariations cell C61 from sheet PartsWarehouse corresponding row, column F
- else do nothing for that cell

-- do this for every cell in range sheet PortBoardVariations from cells C60:EM60.

-- compare for >0 cell under, ie for C60 it is C61, for D60 it is D61 , and so on.

-- there is a chance, that more components will be added in the future to both PortBoardVariations and PartsWarehouse or only to PartsWarehouse.

Example xlsm here :
[Warehouse.xlsm](https://r-man.cz/Download/02%20Random/Warehouse.xlsm)

My code below, I'm not a programmer so I don't know what next to achieve my goal. How to spread it for the whole range C60:EM60?

```
Sub FindAndSubstract_PortBoard()
Dim t
Dim answer As Integer

answer = MsgBox("Substract parts from warehouse?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Message Box Title")
If answer = vbYes Then
If Worksheets("PortBoardVariations").Cells(57, 4).Value <> "" Then 'Test if this parts cell is empty

'this needs to be spreaded for every cell in range C60:EM60, not only Cells(1, 4)
t = Application.Match(Worksheets("PortBoardVariations").Cells(1, 4).Value, Worksheets("PartsWarehouse").Range("A:A"), 0) 'Match same text on sesond sheet

'this also needs to be spreaded for every cell in range F:F, not only "Cells(3, 6)" and range C60:EM60, not only Cells(61, 4)
If Not IsError(t) Then 'if anything is matched, go on
    Worksheets("PartsWarehouse").Cells(3, 6).Value = Worksheets("PartsWarehouse").Range("F" & t) - Worksheets("PortBoardVariations").Cells(61, 4).Value
    MsgBox "Parts were substracted from warehouse" 'notify user operation has been done
Else 'if anything is not matched, show message to user
    MsgBox "Nothing found"
End If
Else
MsgBox "Nothing to substract" 'if anything is matched but no parts needed for this, show message to user
End If
Else
MsgBox "Operation cancelled by user"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

- `parts were not found` notifications are currently disabled due to numerous mismatches in the sample data. You can enable them by removing the comments in the code.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FindAndSubstract_PortBoard()
    Dim answer As Long, iMch, iVal
    Dim c As Range, i As Long, lastCol As Long
    Dim luSht As Worksheet
    Const SUM_ROW = 60  ' row num on PortBoardVariations
    Const LU_SHT = "PartsWarehouse" ' Lookup sheet
    Const LU_COL = 1    ' Looup column
    Const LU_VAL = "F"  ' Value column
    answer = MsgBox("Substract parts from warehouse?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Message Box Title")
    If answer = vbYes Then
        iVal = -1
        Set luSht = Sheets(LU_SHT)
        With Worksheets("PortBoardVariations")
            ' look through each column
            lastCol = .Cells(SUM_ROW, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            For i = 2 To lastCol
                iVal = .Cells(SUM_ROW + 1, i)
                If Len(.Cells(SUM_ROW, i)) > 0 And IsNumeric(iVal) And iVal > 0 Then
                    ' search pats
                    iMch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(.Cells(SUM_ROW, i), luSht.Columns(LU_COL), 0)
                    If IsError(iMch) Then
                        ' MsgBox "Parts [" & .Cells(SUM_ROW, i) & "] were not found"
                    Else
                        ' Update qty
                        With luSht.Cells(iMch, LU_VAL)
                            .Value = .Value - iVal
                        End With
                        MsgBox "Parts [" & .Cells(SUM_ROW, i) & "] were substracted from warehouse"
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End With
        If iVal = -1 Then
            MsgBox "Nothing found"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Operation cancelled by user"
    End If
End Sub
```